# Dynamically updating existing Postgres table (psycopg2) with new columns (time series technical indicators)

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, timescaledb

I'm working with financial time series data (OHLCV) of equities and am augmenting my dataset with financial indicators (e.g. bollinger bands). I have a Postgres/ TimescaleDB hypertable set up and plan on using psycopg2 to run the queries.

What I'd like to do is to be able to automatically and dynamically add columns to my existing database tables with different technical indicators from an existing python library/ module.

So as an example, I have a long table with daily OHLCV and ticker data in columns for ETL processing later. I'd like to run a yet-undetermined number of indicators, say, bollinger bands (upper and lower), RSI, ema, etc. But don't want to have to manually code those new columns in SQL via psycopg2 every time I create a new indicator, but instead have them fed as parameters to get set up automatically in the database - either as a migrated/ new table, or on the existing daily table. (whatever works best)

I've looked around but haven't seen anything that I yet recognize as something that might work for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against modifying your tables repeatedly and instead modelling the data differently. For example, you could create the following tables

```sql
-- Table for the original series
CREATE TABLE series (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  datetime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  symbol TEXT NOT NULL,
  value NUMBER NOT NULL
);

-- Table for the derived indicators
CREATE TABLE indicators (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  series_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  value NUMBER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (series_id) REFERENCES series(id)
);
```

You can then calculate an arbitrary number of indicators for each original series (stored in `series`) and store the derived values in `indicators`. This approach has the additional benefit that you don't need to evaluate all indicators for all time series (or have a bunch of `NULL` columns when you don't evaluate all indicators for all data points).

For example<sup>1</sup>,

```py
import numpy as np
import psycopg2

SYMBOL = "GOOG"
INDICATOR = "EMA"

with psycopg2.connect("your connection string") as conn:
    # Get the data
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("SELECT id, value FROM series WHERE symbol = %s", (SYMBOL,))
        ids, values = np.transpose(cur.fetchall())

    # Calculate the indicator
    indicator_values = evaluate_indicator(values, INDICATOR)

    # Insert the indicator values
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        data = [(series_id, INDICATOR, value) for series_id, value in 
                zip(ids, indicator_values)]
        cur.executemany("INSERT INTO indicators (series_id, name, value) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                        data)
```

Having said that, you can create a new column using the [`ALTER TABLE` command](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) before calculating each new indicator if you want to go down the route of extending the schema of the table.

---

<sup>1</sup> I haven't tested this code so it may contain small niggles.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to give it a shot but I get the idea - rather than restructuring the existing tables (and potentially creating nulls if I don't apply the indicators to every series stored), I can create a similar table with a column for the indicator series name. Although I'm not sure I get the "zip" part. Don't know why I didn't think of that!